# Translating excel function to c# Math.pow not resulting in same values

Tags: c#, excel-formula

I'm trying to translate this function from excel to C#:

=10^(0.1*(-44.1224+3.32*(-97.060520104064452*LOG(0.89*(200/160)))))

excel gives me: 1.2467E-06

```
var value = Math.Pow(10, 0.1 * (-44.1224 + 3.32 * (-97.060520104064452 * Math.Log10(0.89 * (200 / 160)))));
```

C# gives me c#value = 0.0016543260792358536

Anybody has any ideas why I don't get the same value in excel and c#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because C# is rounding for you.

Change this:

```
200 / 160
```

To

```
200.0 / 160.0
```

Output locally:

```
1.24676291550131E-06
```

Comment: More specifically it's doing an integer division which truncates the decimal value of the resulting quotient.

Comment: Thanks Rob/Grant/Shawn! That did it!

Answer (score 0):

It's because 200/160 is being cast to an integer, which truncates your result. To fix the issue, you can do as Rob suggested and write the numerator or demoniator as a floating point number. See [the / operator reference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)